# Translation invariance of a matrix and Inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $\;A\;$ be a $\;2\times 2\;$ matrix with entries $\;A_{ij}=f_{x_i}f_{x_j}-\delta(\frac{1}{2} {\vert \nabla f\vert}^2 -G(f))\;$ where $\;f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^m\;,\;G:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R_{+}\;,\;f_{x_i}=(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_i}, \dots,\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_i})\;$ and $\;\vert \cdot \vert\;$ stands for the Frobenius norm.

$\;A\;$ is invariant under translations. Consider $\;x,y\in \mathbb R^2\;$ two arbitary vectors and take the Euclidean inner product: $\;\langle Ax,y\rangle\;$.

If $\;\bar x\;$ is the translation of $\;x\;$, i.e. $\;\bar x =z+x\;$ for fixed $\;z\in \mathbb R^2\;$, then $\;\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle A(\bar x -z),y \rangle=\langle A\bar x,y\rangle\;(*)$?

**Is $\;(*)\;$ the appropriate way to use the translation invariance of $\;A\;$?**

*NOTE:*
I have proven that $\;\nabla f(\bar x)\;=\nabla f(x)\;$

Please correct me if it's wrong. I've been stuck to this since Saturday... Any help or hints would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "matrix is invariant under translations"?

Comment: The way you wrote it, the matrix is just a constant matrix that does not depend on any "space" or something like that. So the statement is more or less empty, and your formula can only hold if $A = 0$. (look at the formula! If it holds for all vectors $x,y,z$, then you have $Az=0$.) You probably want a matrix *depending* on space, like $A(x)$, but you should become clear of the details.

Comment: @edm That is the question... I haven't any specific definition. The ex just gives that "$\;A\;$ is invariant under translations", this is why I 'm not sure on how to use it..

Comment: @Luke My mistake...I omitted the details about $\;A\;$ because I thought they weren't necessary. Yes my matrix depends on $\;x\;$. I'll edit my post

Comment: @Luke Hope it's more clear now...